# Running downstream pipeline with external gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm having an issue running a cross-project pipeline which utilizes an external gitlab-ci.yml file from another repo. Our setup is as follows:

- projectA/gitlab-config (contains gitlab-ci file)
- projectA/devops (references gitlab-ci file from projectA/gitlab-config in CI/CD settings)
- projectB/application (runs its own gitlab-ci.yml file, which then triggers the downstream pipeline in projectA/devops)

projectA/devops also contains a gitlab-ci file we haven't yet removed due to debugging.

The pipeline in projectA/devops works fine referencing the external config file when used in isolation (run on a feature branch within that repository). However when we attempt to run the downstream pipeline triggered by projectB/application, we get the following error:

`curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 422`

If we remove the reference to the external config file in projectA/devops, the downstream pipeline works as expected (gets created, runs properly, etc.). I believe this must be due to some permissions error, but I can't seem to figure out where the issue is.

The code to trigger the downstream pipeline from projectB/application is as follows:

```
  script:
    - >
      curl --request POST --fail
      --form token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN
      --form ref=master
      --form "variables[UPSTREAM_TAG]=$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
      "https://our.gitlab.instance.com/api/v4/projects/697/trigger/pipeline"
```

Do I need to add a specific Pipeline Trigger for this use case? Without the external file referenced, the $CI_JOB_TOKEN creates the downstream pipeline just fine, so I'm wondering if that has something to do with it.